# How do I correctly connect classes to each other in python with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have got a question how to connect my classes to each other correctly.
I have one main class with my first window where the user has to put in certain infos, after submitting that a new window opens where he has to make the next step.
You can have a look down on my code, the "MyForm"-Class is the mainclass and the "popup"-class is supposed to be the following window. But Im not sure if I linked it properly. It is working but on a weird way. So how to improve this that I dont get in trouble with some more serious projects later.
Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, W, Toplevel
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyForm:
    def thanx(self):
        if any((len(self.e.get().strip()) == 0, len(self.e2.get().strip()) == 0, len(self.e2.get().strip()) == 0)):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
            self.boo = False
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
            self.boo = True
    def callback(self):
       #print("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
       if self.boo:
            f = open("PrivatData.txt", "w+")
            f.write("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
    def popup(self):
        self.root.quit()
        PopUp()
    def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.title("Your privat details")
            Label(self.root, text="Your Name").grid(row = 0, padx = 12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Password").grid(row=1, padx=12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Email").grid(row=2, padx=12, pady=5)
            self.e = Entry(self.root)
            self.e2 = Entry(self.root)
            self.e3= Entry(self.root)
            self.e.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2)
            self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e.focus_set()
            self.show= Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda:[self.thanx(),self.callback(),self.popup()])
            self.quit = Button(self.root,text="Quit", command = self.root.quit)
            self.show.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)
            self.quit.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky = W, pady=4)
            self.root.geometry("230x140")
            self.root.configure(background= "#65499c")
            self.root.mainloop()


class PopUp():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pop = Tk()
        self.pop.title("Next Step")
        self.pop.geometry("500x500")
        self.pop.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= MyForm()
```

As you can see, after clicking the "Submit"-Button, one function is being called which calls the PopUp Class. But thats obviously not the right way. So any improvements?

Comment: As you want to improve your code then please post this question on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `Tk()` doesn't merely open a window, it also starts the Tcl interpreter that's used to process all the Tkinter commands. You need to start that interpreter before doing any other Tkinter stuff, and leave it running for the duration of the program, and don't start another instance of the interpreter, or flakey and confusing things will happen. If you need more windows, use a Toplevel widget for them.